# Перенаправить звук в андроид с микрофона на наушник программно?

Tags: java, android

Как в Андроид (например 4.4), программно на java, воспроизвести звук с микрофона на наушник? Желательно не использовать запись `AudioRecord`, а перенаправить поток MIC на `WiredHeadset`. Подозреваю, что `AudioManager` может, но как?

Для проверки наушников:

```
if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) { }
```

микрофона:

```
if (audioManager.isMicrophoneMute()) {
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
}
```

А вот дальше как ?

Comment: Перенаправить вряд ли получится, все равно придется использовать `AudioRecord` - попробуйте установить минимальный размер буфера

Comment: Вопрос не простой. Возможно кто-то знает, как это можно сделать. Я понимаю, что задержка при малом буфере ничтожна. Но писать буффер и читать его. А потоки соединить ?